# Why does the ping from inside docker is faster than the main OS?

Tags: docker, ping

I tried to ping google from both inside the container running Ubuntu and my main OS. The result is as follow:
[image: Ping result]

Why is the ping from my docker faster than my main OS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known bug - [ping inside container does not ping actual host ip but seems to ping localhost](https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/57).

As of September 2016, it's unfixed.